# How to display only today's or only yesterday's data using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display today's data on my website, but if today no data has been added yet, I want to show yesterday's data.

This is part of the code that I am using, and now it shows today AND yesterday if both data is available, but I want to show only today if both available.

I don't know, how to separate them. Can anybody point me into the right direction?

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));

$result = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM apps WHERE datum = '".$today."' OR datum = '".$yesterday."' AND price > 0 ") or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$cc = 0;

.....

$cc++;  
    if ($cc < $count) {
    echo "\n";
```

Comment: I edited the title, because it was misleading after I reformulated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));

$result = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM apps WHERE datum = '".$today."' AND price > 0 ") or die(mysqli_error());
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0) {
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM apps WHERE datum = '".$yesterday."' AND price > 0 ") or die(mysqli_error());
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
$cc = 0;

.....

$cc++;  
    if ($cc < $count) {
    echo "\n";
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks! I think it will work. I can't upvote your comment because I have not enough reputation :-(

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add `ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1` to the end of your query and read a single row.

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM apps
          WHERE (datum = '".$today."'
             OR datum = '".$yesterday."')
             AND price > 0
          ORDER BY datum DESC
          LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($bd, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    // You have the data here
}
```

Comment: Check for the parenthesis logic ... And you probably don't even need to specify datum conditions ...

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, that there are many entries with the same date for one day and I want to show them all, not only one. I think the LIMIT 1 would give me only one row.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM apps
WHERE datum = (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM apps WHERE price > 0)`

Comment: Or the following `SELECT *
FROM apps
WHERE datum = (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM apps) WHERE price > 0` depending on what your logic is

Comment: That looks even simpler, than the other one. I will try it when today's data arrived and check back! Thanks!

Comment: SELECT * FROM apps WHERE datum = (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM apps WHERE price > 0) <-- This one works, but gives the wrong number. I made a simple counting script and it should count yesterday's data now (because today no data yet), but it gives 202 although there are only 94 entries for yesterday. I believe it counts all the data now with price > 0

Comment: Yes, in this first case MAX(datum) will not select dates for which you have only price <= 0 rows. I wasn't sure what you expect, that's why I added the next comment.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway! For now I think I go with ProudEngeneers' answer and I will experiment a bit further.